# Why don't event delegation work if I mention the outermost selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events, jquery-events

Suppose I make mouseover event delegated by mentioning the outermost selector in target name as:

```js
$(".outer").on("mouseenter", ".outer .inner", function() {

  console.log("YES");

});
```

```css
.outer {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}
.inner {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner">
    Hover
  <span>  
</div>
```

In `$(".outer").on("mouseenter", " .outer .inner",...` If I do not mentioned `.outer` in `.outer .inner` then the code works as:

```js
$(".outer").on("mouseenter", ".inner", function() {

  console.log("YES");

});
```

```css
.outer {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}
.inner {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner">
    Hover
  <span>  
</div>
```

Now as you can see in the console the mouseenter event works. But did it not work in first example? Donn't `.outer .inner` and `.inner` select the same DOM element?

Comment: simply leave away the second argument: $(".outer").on("mouseenter",function...

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery docs, the selector you pass in is:

> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements
>   that trigger the event

So `.outer .inner` does not work, as no such element exists *inside* the `.outer` that triggers the event.